# Apache / mod_wsgi / Django cannot find MySQL shared library

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, django, mod-wsgi

I'm stuck on a case where the MySQL libraries won't be found on a Apache/mod_wsgi/Django deployed server, altough Python alone can import the library correctly.

Here's my Apache log errors:

```
[Tue Jul 10 12:52:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/remote/projects1/pdrtke/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Jul 10 12:52:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Tue Jul 10 12:52:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/remote/projects1/pdrtke/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
[Tue Jul 10 12:52:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
[Tue Jul 10 12:52:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already tried the following:

- Check that Python interpreter can do `import MySQLdb` : *Ok*
- Check that `python manage.py ...` actions requiring database support work: *Ok*
- Check that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to a directory where libmysqlclient_r.so.16 is available : *Ok*
- Attach the `httpd` process with `gdb`, and do a `show env` : The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` too
- Modify the `envvars` file in the bin/http directory to add an `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` (just in case): *Ok*
- Check by a `ldd libmysqlclient_r.so.16` that the library itself does not contain unresolved dependencies
- Check that the `httpd` executable does not have the setuid bit set; which is a documented reason to ignore the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` : *Ok*

None of these actions seem to solve my problem. Is there an obvious thing I forgot to  consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now fixed. That was a stupid mistake of me.

I initially had a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without the good directory so fixed it, but... After changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I issued a `apachectl restart` which, as documented by Apache only kills the child processes, and spawns new children from the existing parent.

So new children kept having the old version of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Now I'm not really sure to understand why I saw the "good" LD_LIBRARY_PATH with `gdb`'s `show environment`. But this is a different story. I'll close my initial question, which is now solved.

Comment: When building MySQLdb Python module, set LD_RUN_PATH environment variable to directory where MySQL shared libraries are and it will embedd that knowledge in the Python C extension and don't have to worry about setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime.